# Preview the first item in a large dict like DataFrame.head()

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

There is a large dict in python.

How to preview the first item or n items in a large dictionaty like DataFrame.head() without print all the dict.

Can I do this without using loop?

Comment: Dictionaries do not have rows, without further information is really hard to answer your question.

Comment: To get the first (key,value) of a large dict without print all the dict

Comment: As Daniel said, Dictionaries in do not have rows, as they are always appended to the end so its in 1 line. They are not ordered either so you cannot get the 1st few number as all the contents are randomly placed. If you want one of the elements then use something like `next(iter(my_dict))`

Comment: I know that dict does not have rows. Maybe calling it as item is more appropriate. So my question is that how to look up first or first n items without print all dict

Answer (score 2):

Convert the dict to Dataframe

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

do

```
df.head()
```

Comment: I think converting to dataframe is not required just to preview few items. Could be done by just iterating over first few items and printing them.